# How to copy numpy 2d array in pandas 2d dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has structure like below:

```
print raster_arr_df

      60.25 60.50 60.75 61.00 61.25 61.50 61.75 62.00 62.25 62.50  ...  94.75  \
3.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
3.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
3.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
4.00    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
4.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
4.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
4.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
5.00    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
5.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
5.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
5.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
6.00    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
6.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
6.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
6.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
7.00    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
7.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
7.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
7.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
8.00    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
8.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
8.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
8.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
9.00    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
9.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
9.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
9.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
10.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
10.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
10.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
...     ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  ...    ...   
35.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
36.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
36.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
36.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
36.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
37.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
37.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
37.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
37.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
38.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
38.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
38.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
38.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
39.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
39.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
39.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
39.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
40.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
40.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
40.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
40.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
41.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
41.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
41.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
41.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
42.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
42.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
42.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
42.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
43.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   

      95.00 95.25 95.50 95.75 96.00 96.25 96.50 96.75 97.00  
3.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
3.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
3.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
4.00    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
4.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
4.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
4.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
5.00    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
5.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
5.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
5.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
6.00    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
6.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
6.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
6.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
7.00    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
7.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
7.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
7.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
8.00    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
8.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
8.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
8.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
9.00    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
9.25    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
9.50    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
9.75    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
10.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
10.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
10.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
...     ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  
35.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
36.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
36.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
36.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
36.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
37.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
37.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
37.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
37.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
38.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
38.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
38.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
38.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
39.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
39.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
39.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
39.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
40.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
40.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
40.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
40.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
41.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
41.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
41.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
41.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
42.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
42.25   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
42.50   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
42.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
43.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  

[160 rows x 148 columns]
```

And my numpy array looks like below:

```
print raster_arr

[[ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.64464766  0.78923023
   0.90317035]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  1.39210367  2.56416273
   1.28261185]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.63526356  0.66092908
   1.5844413 ]
 ..., 
 [ 2.04395676  1.64457083  1.70771551 ...,  8.11063385  2.57144356
   1.60219038]
 [ 2.46784496  2.20636702  1.82298481 ...,  2.11637998  2.1444006
   2.13336754]
 [ 3.26898718  3.19584775  2.69124269 ...,  2.74416089  2.27447248
   6.18890047]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I want to copy all the values in numpy to pandas dataframe with the define index and columns in dataframe.

The shape of both the pandas dataframe and the numpy array is the same.

Comment: Maybe try `DataFrame` constructor like `print pd.DataFrame(raster_arr, index=raster_arr_df.index, columns=raster_arr_df.columns)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> pandas.DataFrame(<*numpy array*>, index=df.index, columns=df.columns, dtype=None,
>   copy=False)

where: 
data is your numpy array,
index is your rows for dataframe,
columns is the columns.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor like: `pd.DataFrame(data=raster_arr, index=raster_arr_df.index, columns=raster_arr_df.columns)`:

> **data** : numpy ndarray (structured or homogeneous), dict, or DataFrame
>      Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, or list-like objects
>
> **index** : Index or array-like
>      Index to use for resulting frame. Will default to np.arange(n) if no indexing information part of input data and no index provided
>
> **columns** : Index or array-like
>      Column labels to use for resulting frame. Will default to np.arange(n) if no column labels are provided

Sample:

```
print raster_arr_df
     a    b    c    d
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

print raster_arr
[[1 1 3 0]
 [4 2 6 0]
 [4 3 9 5]]

print pd.DataFrame(data=raster_arr, index=raster_arr_df.index, columns=raster_arr_df.columns)
   a  b  c  d
1  1  1  3  0
2  4  2  6  0
3  4  3  9  5
```

Comment: Sorry, but why my answer was unaccepted? Thanks for explanation. Is something wrong?